# Is there already reached consensus on network upgrades like Taproot, Submarine Swaps?

Tags: lightning-network, bitcoin-core-development, bip, schnorr-signatures, taproot

I have read about some very interesting new protocol amendments. I am not asking for their explanations, but would be great if anyone explained  their current status, if they are still considered to be implemented (do you know when?), or if they have been removed from consideration...

Is majority of relevant stakeholders in consensus and for these changes, any struggles to be expected like with segwit?

1. MAST/TAPROOT
2. SCHNORR
3. Submarine Swaps
4. Drivechain Sidechain, by Paul Sztorc

Answer (score 3):

> 1. MAST/TAPROOT
> 2. SCHNORR

These improvements are specified in [BIP340](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0340.mediawiki), [BIP341](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0341.mediawiki), and [BIP342](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0340.mediawiki). These documents are fairly mature, and there seems to be community traction for them (though, disclaimer: I may be biased as I'm a co-author), but it's inherently hard to predict when activation will happen.

> 3. Submarine Swaps

This is a Lightning feature, as far as I know. It requires no Bitcoin protocol changes, and as far as I understand it, no Lightning protocol changes either - it's usable today.

> 4. Drivechain Sidechain, by Paul Sztorc

I haven't paid much attention to this.